# Implementing Syntax highlighter for RichText box (similar to C# in VS)

Tags: c#, comments, syntax-highlighting

I have got this simple syntax highlighter, but need to highlight the comments and strings as well. So it makes different colors for the syntax, then for comments and also for simple strings as well. Can you help me with that?

```
klicslova = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

string Csharp = "abstract,event,new,struct,as,explicit,null,switch,base,extern,this,false,operator,throw,break,finally,out,true,fixed,override,try,case,params,typeof,catch,for,private,foreach,protected,checked,goto,public,unchecked,if,readonly,unsafe,implicit,ref,continue,in,return,using,virtual,default,interface,sealed,volatile,delegate,internal,do,is,sizeof,while,double,lock,stackalloc,else,static,namespace,";

string datove_typy = "bool,object,byte,float,class,uint,char,ulong,ushort,const,decimal,int,sbyte,short,void,long,enum,string";

string php_funkce = "mb_internal_en­coding,mb_strlen,mb_strpos,mb_substr,mb_strtoupper,mb_strtolower,trim,htmlspecialchars,htmlspecialchars_decode,strip_tags,nl2br,str_replace,strtr,parse_str,explode,implode,hash,session_start(),$_SESSION";

string php_slova = "and,array,clone,declare,die,echo,elseif,empty,enddeclare,endfor,endforeach,endif,endswitch,endwhile,eval,exit,extends,final,function,global,implements,include,include_once,instanceof,insteadof,isset,list,or,print,require,require_once,trait,unset,use,var,xor";

string html = "head,/,body,meta,title,link,div,a,ul,ol,header,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,button,span,form,label,input,img,p,iframe,tr,td,th,table,footer,html";

string Csharp_dodatek = "Console.ReadLine,Console.WriteLine,Console.Write,{,},(,),(),{}";

string komenty = "//qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890";

foreach(string slovo in komenty.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Orange);

foreach(string slovo in Csharp.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Red);

foreach(string slovo in datove_typy.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Blue);

foreach(string slovo in php_funkce.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Red);

foreach(string slovo in php_slova.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Green);

foreach (string slovo in html.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Blue);

foreach (string slovo in Csharp_dodatek.Split(','))
    klicslova.Add(slovo, Color.Green);

        public static string Zvyraznovac(string text)
        {
            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            rtb.Text = text;
            rtb.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8.75f, FontStyle.Regular);

            int index;

            foreach(var vstup in klicslova)
            {
                index = 0;

                while ((index = rtb.Find(vstup.Key, index, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)) != -1)
                {
                    rtb.Select(index, vstup.Key.Length);
                    rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font.FontFamily, rtb.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
                    rtb.SelectionColor = vstup.Value;
                    index += 1;
                }
            }

            return rtb.Rtf;
```

Comment: It is vary hard to help with this question as it is essentially asking for guidance on a project that is done strictly with educational/entertainment purposes. If you want syntax highlighter - find existing one. If you have *concrete* question with an approach you are investigating - [edit] question to clarify that.. But "can you help me" is really not enough details for SO question.

Comment: Don't develop in Polish. Work in English. See, when you one day you will want to sell your product, English will be better

Comment: There are many syntax highlighters based on RichTextBox, find any of them. For full language syntax you must implement language tokenizer. Then split source code to tokens and colorize these tokens.